# Icon with tooltip on antd form item

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I am working with Antd Form Item and I have to put an icon with tooltip like this: [image]

And here is my code:

```
 <Item label={'Password'} name={'password'} className={'password'} rules={[{ required: true, message: t('Feld ist erforderlich') }]}>
            <Password size="large" />
            <PasswordStrength password={password} />
 </Item>
```

Any idea? Please help! Thank you!

Comment: what is your question? Must be you want to add a tooltip above input?  the item in Antd has property is a tooltip, you can see in docs: https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-required-mark

Comment: this tooltip beside label, you can custom CSS of Ant

Comment: tooltip property isn't recognized :(

Comment: Are you use upgrade version Antd lastest?

Answer (score 6):

Solution 1: You can custom label in Form item, follow my code

```
<Item
    label={
      <div>
        Label a{" "}
        <Tooltip title="Tooltip with customize">
          <InfoCircleOutlined />
        </Tooltip>
      </div>
    }
  >
    <Input placeholder="input placeholder" />
  </Item>
```

Solution 2: you can upgrade new version Antd, and use property tooltip

I hope it useful for you.

Comment: If I apply the first solution, I get something like this, which is not the expected one: Password 
 @ : *, the icon is not in the right position

Comment: You can choose a icon other

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I got same problem and work around by below solution:

I don't set label attribute for Form.Item, then add a Row on top of Form Item including label and tooltip icon

```
    <Row justify="space-between">
      <Col>
        <span>Mật Khẩu</span>
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <Tooltip title='tooltip text'>
            <ExclamationCircleOutlined />
        </Tooltip>
      </Col>
    </Row>
     <Form.Item>
       <Input.Password />
     </Form.Item>
```